# How to display an enum with duplicate values in a .NET PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I have an enum that contains duplicate values. For example:

```
public enum DataVals : byte 
{
    C1_Route1to2 = 1,
    C4_Route3to5 = 1,
    C6_Route1to2 = 2,
    C7_Route3to5 = 2
}
```

The values `C#` are just internal values within my application. Depending on which route is selected by the user, `route` is another property in the class, a `1` could mean use `C1` or `C4`. The problem is I am using a `PropertyGrid` in my `Winform` and this property displays the duplicate values as having the same name. So `C1_Route1to2` shows up twice instead of both `C1_Route1to2` and `C4_Route3to5`.

How do I tell the `PropertyGrid` to display each unique name, rather than duplicating the values?

Comment: Add a converter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.enumconverter?view=netframework-4.7.1

Comment: Does it make sense to do this, though? You're saying that `DataVals.C1_Route1to2 == DataVals.C4_Route3to5`, is this true? If not, I think it would be better to do this in a different way.. Maybe define just one value like `C1_Route1to2_OR_C4_Route3to5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with Gabriel, you could achieve what you need using the TypeConverter as I mentioned before. You might need to change the editor to allow selecting more than one enum if it has the FlagsAttribute...

Place the attribute:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ComplexEnumConverter ))]
public enum DataVals : byte 
{
    C1_Route1to2 = 1,
    C4_Route3to5 = 1,
    C6_Route1to2 = 2,
    C7_Route3to5 = 2
}
```

And here is the converter:

```
public class ComplexEnumConverter : EnumConverter
    {
        public bool IsFlagged { get; }

        public string[] EnumValues { get; }

        public ComplexEnumConverter(Type type)
            : base(type)
        {
            IsFlagged = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(type).OfType<FlagsAttribute>().Any();
            EnumValues = Enum.GetNames(type);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return destinationType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            var str = value as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                var values = str.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim());
                var enumValue = Enum.Parse(EnumType, values.First());
                if (IsFlagged)
                {
                    var temp = (int)enumValue;
                    foreach (var item in values.Skip(1))
                    {
                        temp |= (int)Enum.Parse(EnumType, item);
                    }

                    enumValue = temp;
                }

                return enumValue;
            }

            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            var type = value?.GetType();
            if (type == EnumType)
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                int k = (int)value;
                foreach (var item in Enum.GetNames(type))
                {
                    var current = (int)Enum.Parse(type, item);
                    if ((k & current) == current)
                    {
                        list.Add(item);
                    }
                }

                return list.Aggregate((c, n) => $"{c}, {n}");
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return context.PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsEnum;
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return context.PropertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsEnum;
        }

        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return new StandardValuesCollection(EnumValues);
        }
    }
```